# How get data from C# Model using SQl, EF and linQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Below are 3 classes that I have built and I want to get and loop data from table RestaurantVersion calling from Class 3. Can someone help me out to accomplish this? I am very new to C# and trying to learn but this part is somewhat confusing to me. Thank you!

[image: Class 1]

[image: Class 2]

[image: Class 3]

Comment: What is *Class 3*?

Comment: Class 3 is the class I want to out put the data and loop over it to do some processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
public class ProcessProofs
{
    public void Process()
    {
        var context = new RestaurantVersion();

        List<DbRestaurantVersion> restaurantVersions = context.RestaurantVersions.ToList();

        foreach (DbRestaurantVersion item in restaurantVersions)
        {
            //process item
        }
    }
}
```

You can build complex `Linq` query to retrieve data that you need. `DbSet` doesn't contain any data at all but when you call `ToList` or iterating through `DbSet` collection Entity Framework builds sql query based on `Linq` expression, sends it to database and retrieves data mapped to classes.

Comment: Class 2 line 12 is where the context is coming from?

Comment: @SGekko What context?

Comment: @SGekko You have dbcontext in your app - RestaurantVersion inherited from DbContext. You instantiate the context and get values from tables via its properties.

Comment: Maybe I should have said that is where the entities/data is coming from?

Comment: @SGekko Data is coming from database.

Comment: Guess I am not asking correctly. Is the data from the database being stored in the DbSet on line 12 located in Class 2 and is that being called in Class 3?

Comment: @SGekko No, data is not stored in dbset at all. You can build a linq expression to get data what you need and when you call `ToList` C# code sends an sql query to database to retrieve data.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @SGekko You are welcome. Please consider upvoting/marking answer as accepted is it was helpful.